# Python while sampling

Tags: python, while-loop, sample

I'm searching to make a loop to go throw samples till I reach the result. Example:

```
    i=(list(np.random.randint(2, size=5)),list(np.random.randint(2,  size=2)),list(np.random.randint(2, size=7)),list(np.random.randint(2, size=7)),list(np.random.randint(2, size=9)),list(np.random.randint(2, size=8)),list(np.random.randint(2, size=7)))

    tot=0
    for j in range(0,len(anytable)):
        if resp(i,(anytable.iloc[j,0:7].tolist())):  #this function "resp"  gives me True and False and add 1 to variable "tot"
           tot=tot+1
```

Now I want to stop till I have to `tot>=100` .
So I have to generate many "i" samples lists till I get to `tot>=100`.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: I guess you are looking for the break statement? see here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: What is `t` ???

Comment: t is variable tot, i made a mistake

Comment: Do you want to break your loop when one of two variables hits a certain limit, but you do not know which comes first?

Answer (score 0):

From guessing I would say, this could be your solution.

```
j, tot = 1, 1
while j<len(anytable) and tot<100 :
    tot += int( resp(i,(anytable.iloc[j,0:7].tolist())) )
    j   += 1
```

The condition is false if one of the inequations is false. The incementing operator `+=` on `tot` is adding the integer representation of a boolean `True = 1` or `False = 0` to the value of `tot`.